# Declaring and assigning variables with file scope in C

Tags: c, initialization, variable-declaration

Say I declare the following variable:

```
int num;
num = 0;

int main(void)
{
        /* ... */
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The compiler will complain about `num` being undeclared and that it will default to type `int`. This does not happen when I do it all in one step:

```
int num = 0;
```

or if I move the assignment into `main()`:

```
int main(void)
{
        num = 0;
        /* ... */
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I once read an explanation for this behavior but I cannot find it anymore. Could someone update me again.

I'm compiling with

```
gcc -std=c11 -O2 -g -pedantic -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -v
```

Comment: You intend `num = 0;` as a statement; statements can only fall within function bodies.  Instead, the compiler is interpreting it as a variable declaration, but without a type.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Firstly, there's no such thing as *declaration statement* in C. In C language declarations are not statements. Declarations are always just declarations. *Declaration statements* exists in C++, but not in C. Secondly, even in C++ *statements* have to reside inside functions. Even in C++ declarations made in namespace scope are still just *declarations*, not *declaration statements*.

Comment: @AnT: You're right, removed. I never realized that. In C++, a declaration statement comprises only a small subset of all possible declarations. (In particular, naked semicolons don't seem to be valid at namespace scope in C++.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`num = 0;` is a statement that can exist only inside a function. It cannot exist in a global scope.

If you put a statement outside a function, it's wrong and not allowed. Simply think this like, if you have a statement outside all the functions, in a global scope, when and how that statement can be executed? So, that's wrong.

A special case, initialization while defining is allowed in a form of `int num = 0;`

Comment: Just an addition: The initializer for a global variable must be a _constant expression_ for the same reason: it has to be evaluated at compile-time,